# Page redirect using call back function in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

I have created a validate function in Javascript for validation the form. Now I want to create another function redirect which is to be used as a call back function to redirect to another html page after form validation..how to do that??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].   If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the location.replace() function like this -

```js
validate(sometext, redirect)

function validate(text, callback){
  //somelogic
  callback("https://google.com")
}

function redirect(url) {
  location.replace(url)
}
```